# error failure AH01075: Error dispatching req uest to : (polling)

Tags: apache2, php-8.1

[proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 28135] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: [client ########:44146] AH01075: Error dispatching req
uest to : (polling)

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/q/46594731/18667225 ! If this doesn’t help please read [ask] and try to give some more information of your specific problem.