# The timeout specified has expired

Tags: php, wordpress, performance, apache, logging

my wordpress website is fast and slow by moment with
apache log give the following message:

```
[Tue Jun ] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 6432] (70007)The timeout specified has expired: 
[client ] AH01075: Error dispatching request to : (polling)
```

Can you help me to resolve that, please?
Regards !

Comment: The reason you cannot submit a question without a certain amount of content is so that you create a well asked question with enough information for us to attempt a sensible answer. It is not there to encourage you to repeat the same information more than once

Comment: Did you look at the answers in this {Question and Answer set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46594731) to see if it helps you?